# What are the minimum specifications for a Scala development machine?

Tags: scala, memory, io, ide, cpu

I need to spec out a new computer. I'm only going to use this computer for developing Scala software. I'm going to be running Intellij, doing builds with Maven and SBT, and perhaps firing up a couple of Virtual Machines. I'm going to building a mixture of fairly large Play Framework and micro-services. What is a reasonable machine for doing this work?

Comment: The most important thing, a lot of memory. I would say at least 8GB, better 16GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn your focus to these key components:

### CPU

Since Scala (and the compiler) parallelize well: go for more cores, the more the better. Depending on your budget you can think of multi-CPU systems.

### RAM

A lot of RAM helps a lot. I am pretty happy with 16GB, but depending on the size you are planning you might need more, but 16 is a decent amount. You can also think about using RAM to make a RAM-disk for faster compilation etc.

### HDD

You definitely want to have a fast SSD. You should look for one with high IOPS, the transfer rate is for developing not that important. If you have a large budget, you can go for 2 SSDs in RAID-0. But be aware that some RAID controllers are not fast enough and will not give you the full possible performance of your SSD RAID.

Comment: So you're claiming that scalac is a parallel compiler?

Comment: scalac is AFAIK not a parallel compiler. But when used together with a build system to build several components the parallelization comes from the build system invoking multiple instances of the compiler. Aside from that there are projects that already parallelize some parts of the compiling process (like [this](http://magarciaepfl.github.io/scala/) one)

Comment: Hum, for good raw compilation times when working on a single project, cores don't matter much (above some minimum like 4), frequency does. The more GHz the better.

Comment: @masgo, *But when used together with a build system to build several components the parallelization comes from the build system invoking multiple instances of the compiler* sbt? gradle? maven? I only aware of **running tests** in parallel. I think you are misguiding op on CPU parallelism significance (esp. in *compiler* part). Correct me with proofs if I wrong.

Comment: The question was asking for minimum specs, not a dream machine.

Comment: Good to know that I'm unable to run Scala on my machine because I don't meet these minimum specs. I'll have to show my manager this post as reason for not being able to do my work.

Answer (score 2):

The Scala compiler still has poor parrelisation. I doubt that's going to change before you'll be due an upgrade. For this reason I would suggest as a minimum using a Haswell 4670. Going up to an i7 will probably be of doubtful benefit. if you want to spend extra money over-clock a 4770K or a 4670k. If you've really got money to burn use an Ivybridge 4960x, but you won't see much benefit for that extra money. Intel beats AMD on core for core performance. Make sure you've got a 4 memory slot motherboard. 2 Eight Gig DDR3 1600 sticks are probably more than sufficient but allow for an upgrade to 32 Gig in a year or so's time when hopefully memory's come down in price.

As already stated a decent SSD. Run your operating System, your IDE and your projects off the SSD. You'll want a SATA drive for mass storage.

Anyway above $1500 or so for the Base unit diminishing returns set in rapidly. Unless you've really got money to burn.

You'll probably want a graphic cards to run multiple monitors. An AMD 7790 should do the job. I'm assuming that a budget of a 1000 to 1500 dollars for a base unit is not as issue. Personally I find 3 24" 1920 * 1200 monitors just right for civilised development.